# Why Lm7905 give positive voltage instead negative in Lt-spice simulation at EasyEda software?

Tags: ltspice

I have selected the Lm7905 and lm7909 in simulation mode in [EasyEda](https://easyeda.com) software like this:

[image]

Which could be seen here:

https://easyeda.com/editor#mode=sim,id=|1f8d2e91e71e4daeba70b25b2bc15fa6|4b4839cf2c8c497b981f4f62a1a04f0a|310de4f753f3458f88e92d9f05ab0594

So as you could see the multi meters have the same 5V and don't show -5V or -9V?

Alternative link:

https://easyeda.com/forum/topic/Why-Lm7905-give-positive-voltage-instead-negative-in-Lt-spice-simulation-at-EasyEda-software-d9f1a389e39442f197064ccd155094f5
Thanks.

Comment: Probably because you are applying a positive voltage to it.  The 79xx regulators don't convert positive voltages to negative, they regulate negative voltages.  You'll need to feed it with a negative voltage, ie, the *positive* side of your voltage source goes to ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LM79xx requires a **negative** input voltage, not positive.

Comment: Thanks @Dave_Tweed, So have could declare this question solved?

Comment: I have used IC555 and ...  for negative voltage maker [here](https://easyeda.com/elasa.group/neative-voltage-source-with-ic555), is there any simple and cheap  IC   for this usage?

Comment: @modern it's called switch-mode power supply (SMPS), and you'll find literally thousands of chips that do that. Simply go to the website of pretty much any large silicon chip manufacturer (TI, analog devices, NXP, ST, Maxim…) and look for them in the "power management" category.